# Dual boot linux/windows from UEFI

Tags: windows, multi-boot, uefi

A few month ago I've installed Linux as a second system. As a boot manager I use rEFInd.

Unfortunately, last windows update changed it somehow back to the Windows Boot Manager. 
Now, my computer automatically boots to Windows. But I've figured out that I can boot to Linux through going in windows to setting > Update & security > restore > Advanced setup, then choosing Linux in other operating systems. 
Is it somehow possible to always go to this menu when you startup a PC? Ive allready tried to reinstall reFIND and this solved the problem, but is it really possible to do this using UEFI? I know about bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions command, but it does not give you a choice of operating system. And also I've disabled Secure Boot on my Motherboard settings (I have an MSI motherboard, and in boot mode options, Legacy+UEFI is selected)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you have fastboot turned on?

Comment: Have you checked your boot order in your mobo settings? Make sure rEFInd's entry is above everything- the Windows Boot Manager, the drive itself, anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for an answers, No, my fastboot is turned off, and I really want just use UEFI to boot both systems, if its possible

Comment: Do you mean UEFI, rEFInd, or the Windows Boot Manager? The UEFI bootloader (as far as I'm aware) isn't a visual one, it doesn't let you pick, it tries each entry sequentially until it fails- just like the BIOS bootloader. rEFInd can boot both Windows and Linux, and if you want to reliably use both Windows and Linux, this is the one you should use. The Windows Boot Manager is only built for Windows, and while it can boot Linux, don't consider it reliable at doing it.